# symfony2 migrations sql file

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm

I want update my trigger from live, and I want to know if I can use migrations for that because I tried 2 alternative in my migrations:

```
public function up(Schema $schema)
    {
        // this up() migration is auto-generated, please modify it to your needs
        $this->abortIf($this->connection->getDatabasePlatform()->getName() != 'mysql', 'Migration can only be executed safely on \'mysql\'.');

        $stmt = $this->connection->prepare(file_get_contents(__DIR__ . '/Version20150929103205/new_trigger_procedure.sql'));
        $stmt->execute();

        $this->addSql(file_get_contents(__DIR__ . '/Version20150929103205/new_trigger_procedure.sql'));
    }
```

but not work. My sql file have multiple declaration. Is a possibility to run it with migrations?

Here is a model:

`DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS trigger_1;
Create Trigger trigger_1 BEFORE...
DROP Trigger IF EXISTS trigger_2;
Create Trigger trigger_2 Before ...
.
.
.`

Comment: What's in the .sql file, can you post it? Try executing the same statement with the same user on the same server in console.

Comment: I update my question ... model is my query's in my sql file.

Comment: OK, now execute the contents of this file on the server in a MySQL console logged in as the user that executes SQL from within your application and see if it's successfully executed. In theory it should be possible from Symfony migrations file but you likely have a permission issue.

Comment: I run it ... but the problem is if you have more then 1 sintax with semicolons migration say run it, but he don't execute in db (no error, it look like every thing is ok but isn't). I see only solution to make n sql file for every query. If you know a better solution to put all query in 1 sql and my migration to run it.

Comment: @Laurentiu, have you tried running `$this->connection->executeQuery($fileContents);`?

Comment: yes ... but don't change it ... this make me confusez ... why don't work with simple connection to run a query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the only solution was to split everything someting like that:

```
$this->addSql('DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS trigger_1');
$this->addSql('...');
...
```

or to do someting like that:

```
$querys = explode(file_get_contents($file));
foreach($querys as $query){
   $this->addSql($query);
}
```

but in this case you should be sure you have instruction what end with `;` and not have `;` in values at inserted `query` or everything else situations.